# What is the purpose of Virtual attributes in Dynamic CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When you create a custom picklist attribute, Dynamic crm create a nother virtual attribute. I want to know the purpose of virtual attribute in dynamic crm.

Comment: first I've heard of Virtual Attribute.  Can you give a screen shot or description?

Comment: Are you sure you're on CRM 2013 ? Picklist attributes pertain to CRM4. Also, what's a "virtual" attribute ? Never heard of them.

Comment: Hi all, virtual attributes are created when you create a picklist attribute but i don't know its purpose

Answer (score 5):

The "virtual" Name column for OptionSet and Boolean attributes only exists in the filtered views that are created in the database. They only are there for your convenience.

When you take a look at the filtered view's underlying SQL, you can see the Name attribute is not a table column. Instead it is the result of a join with the StringMap table. This way it makes it easier to get the display text of options in the proper language, which is very helpful when creating reports.